# Mysql how to split columns according to the condition?

Tags: mysql

I have a [db fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae2404/1) in which I have a table. In this table, there are codes and their descriptions which are on the same field. i.e. for example if the code is `101` then its description `MDI Reset` is also in the same column. These both are identified by an id `271`, the id of the codes, and `285` is the id of the description.

**Actual Table**

```
+------------+--------+----------+---------------+
| id     | did    | source    |         code     |
+------------+--------+----------+---------------+
|    101 | 271    | 101       |        200300B8  |
+------------+--------+----------+---------------+
|    102 | 271    | 102       |        200300B9  |
+------------+--------+----------+---------------+
|    151 | 285    | MDI Reset |        200300B8  |
+------------+--------+----------+---------------+
|    152 | 285    | Parameterization | 200300B9  |
+------------+--------+----------+---------------+
```

**Output I want**

```
------+----------+-------------------------------+
| source 1  | source 2          |      code      |
+------------+--------+----------+---------------+
| 101       |  MDI Reset        |      200300B8  |
+------------+--------+----------+---------------+
| 102       |  Parameterization |      200300B9  |
+------------+--------+----------+---------------+
```

I want to put The description and its source side by side just like above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table design is awkward, but we can handle your requirement via a self join:

```sql
SELECT e1.source AS source1, e2.source AS source2, e1.code
FROM events e1
INNER JOIN events e2
    ON e2.code = e1.code
WHERE
    e1.source REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' AND
    e2.source NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

The joining logic here matches pairs of records sharing the same code.  The first record in the pair has a pure number as its source, while the second record does not have a pure number as its source.

Here is a link to your updated [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae2404/4).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call the columns you specifically want to see and rename the titles of the columns within the statement.

```
select dmbmbs as 'source 1', bm as 'source 2', mbbm as 'code' from sp_bmzd
```